# mail server configuration through exim

Tags: linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mail server configuration through exim](https://serverfault.com/questions/296955/mail-server-configuration-through-exim)

I am Configure my mail server and i am able to send and recive mail in local server but i am not able to send and recive mail in out side server and i am also not able to telnet with my smtp server.when i am sending mail thenn it's show this error.

```
 delivering 1Qo8wq-0003Lc-AM
T: remote_smtp for prabhat.mishra@ebizontek.com
LOG: MAIN
  ** prabhat.mishra@ebizontek.com R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp: retry time not reached for any host after a long failure period
LOG: MAIN
  Error while reading message with no usable sender address (R=1Qo8wq-0003Lc-AM): at least one malformed recipient address: root@ - domain missing or malformed
LOG: MAIN
  Process failed (1) when writing error message to root@ (frozen)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your log sample, the "to:" address is malformed - "at least one malformed recipient address: root@ - domain missing or malformed". You probably need to check the email client as the starting point with this one.

"also not able to telnet with my smtp server"

In which direction? To which host(s)?

Comment: telnet my domain ip 25 it's show connaction refused by remote server

Comment: How about "telnet 127.0.0.1 25" from the server itself?

Comment: telnet 110.***.***.*** 25

Comment: Ok, so it is failing when connecting to the destination SMTP servers from your SMTP server? If so, you might check your server's IP to ensure it is not on any blacklist/blocklist listings.

Comment: No i am check it.it's not blacklist.

Comment: Is it even connecting? Can you connect to any remote SMTP servers?

Comment: i am only able to connect with my loopback ip 127.0.0.1

Comment: Then you need to take a look at firewalls - local server, local network, ISP and so on... Any chance you are on a residential ISP account? Some ISPs will block port 25 from leaving their managed environments to head of SMTP-bot situations (and outright spammers).

Comment: the total error is below when i am sending mail through exim

Comment: Do you have any other SMTP servers that can successfully send through the same ISP configuration?