# mail server configuration through exim

Tags: linux

the total error is below when i am sending mail through exim

```
    LOG: MAIN
  <= root@ U=root P=local S=345
[root@localhost ~]# delivering 1QoU2R-0001ox-L0
T: remote_smtp for may@gmail.com
Connecting to ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com [74.125.127.27]:25 ... failed: Connection timed out (timeout=5m)
LOG: MAIN
  ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com [74.125.127.27] Connection timed out
LOG: MAIN
  == may@gmail R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp defer (110): Connection timed out
LOG: MAIN
  ** may@gmail.com: retry timeout exceeded
LOG: MAIN
  Error while reading message with no usable sender address (R=1QoU2R-0001ox-L0): at least one malformed recipient address: root@ - domain missing or malformed
LOG: MAIN
  Process failed (1) when writing error message to root@ (frozen)
```

Comment: This is basically a respin of http://serverfault.com/questions/296550/mail-server-configuration-through-exim where user90168 is just answer shopping.

Comment: I think it's a different question, but it's no better than the other one.

Answer (score 2):

It says you are trying to connect to `74.125.127.27` (which has an ESMTP server listening on port 25) and the attempt is timing out. This isn't usually a problem with the mail server's configuration, most likely it's network related. If this command fails, then it's network related (otherwise, I don't know what's wrong)

```
telnet 74.125.127.27 25
```

If it only says `Trying 74.125.127.27...`, then it's probably one of the following problems:

- For some reason, 74.125.127.27 isn't listening to port 25 when you tried to send mail (note that when I did an mx lookup for gmail.com, that IP didn't show up as one of their mail exchanges)
- Something between you and 74.125.127.27 is broken and you're not able to connect
- Something you've set up locally is blocking your attempt to connect.

The first two is something out of your control, but the local issue may be firewall settings, maybe your router, etc. It's also possible your upstream provider is blocking outgoing connections to port 25.

The other error message is probably because you're sending an email with an envelope sender of `root@` (no domain).

Comment: It"s showing                                                                                                                                                 telnet 74.125.127.27 25

Trying 74.125.127.27...
telnet: connect to address 74.125.127.27: Connection timed out
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out

Comment: Then it seems to be a network problem and not exim. I've just now connected to 74.125.127.2, port 25 so it's not the first item. If you can ping 74.125.127.2 then it's probably your provider blocking you or something local (maybe your firewall?)

Comment: Yes I am able to ping with 74.125.127.27.5                                                                                                                                       [root@localhost ~]# ping 74.125.127.27
PING 74.125.127.27 (74.125.127.27) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 74.125.127.27: icmp_seq=1 ttl=45 time=251 ms
64 bytes from 74.125.127.27: icmp_seq=2 ttl=45 time=253 ms
64 bytes from 74.125.127.27: icmp_seq=3 ttl=44 time=252 ms
64 bytes from 74.125.127.27: icmp_seq=4 ttl=44 time=265 ms
64 bytes from 74.125.127.27: icmp_seq=5 ttl=44 time=252 ms